# Can I store pumpkin seeds that have gotten damp?

Tags: seeds, germination, pumpkins

I'm rather new to gardening, and I bought some pumpkin seeds today, [Queensland Blue](http://www.seedsavers.org/queensland-blue-squash) if it matters. I planted some and was planning to keep the rest, but they all accidentally got a little wet.

Will these seeds now germinate unavoidably? If so I'll make space to plant them all, but if there's any way to keep them for future years I'd prefer that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order for a seed to germinate it needs to imbibe sufficient water to rehydrate the food sources and molecular machinery inside the seed, and this results in the seed swelling. This is also a temperature sensitive process. So, if the seed hasn't swollen, dry it off to prevent it imbibing any water and store in a cool location.

Answer (score 7):

Dry them off and put them on a paper towel. If they still sprout, you can plant them then.